# Chrome not loading SVG favicon

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, favicon

I have a page with a SVG as my only favicon using the following line in the `head` element:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

This works correctly in Firefox, however Chrome (109.0.5414.120) doesn't give the page a favicon. Chrome's DevTools with cache disabled don't show any requests for `favicon.svg`. Nothing is logged to the console.

What could be causing this to not work?